# Getting image from Firebase and creating stripe.File

Tags: python, python-requests, stripe-payments, python-imageio

I am trying transfer a file to Stripe from a firebase database using the  `stripe.File.create()` method. Here is the code that I am using:

```
file_url = storage.child("/path/to/file").get_url(token=None)
response = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    stripe.File.create(
        purpose="identity_document",
        file=img
    )
```

But when I run this code I get:

```
Request req_E7fskNVgpHHlRm: Invalid hash
```

I believe I am getting the correct image from firebase, since I can run the following line and get the image saved to my local drive:

```
img.save("test.jpg")
```

But Stripe doest not seem to like the file format that I am giving it. I believe the file has to be supplied in binary mode, so perhaps I simply need to do edit the line `img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))` to get the file in binary mode.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the correct MIME type when sending the file? Have a look at https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload#uploading-a-file

Comment: How do you specify the MIME type? Is that in the header of the file? I can save as a .jpg. The documentation does not show how to set the correct MIME type

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))` creates a `JpegImageFile` object, which is an image. But Stripe is expecting a file, something like `io.BufferedReader` object. So Stripe is saying that you are supplying an image, when really it just wants a file. To fix the issue, just change the `img =` line to:

```
imgFile = BytesIO(response.content)
```